# When do we need to add file extension when importing JavaScript modules?

Tags: javascript, node.js

When importing modules, I noticed sometimes imported files have their extension, example:

```
import { myFunc } from './foo.js';
```

Whereas other libraries, the imports do not:

```
import { myFunc } from './foo';
```

Is this related to ES modules vs CommonJS modules?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

It depends on your runtime and compilation environment, and also on whether you are using ES modules (the `import` syntax) or CommonJS modules (the `require` syntax). Find below an overview of the most common cases:

- Webpack (used by [Create React App](https://create-react-app.dev) and others tools) works with ES modules like so:

> If the path has a file extension, then the file is bundled straightaway.
> Otherwise, the file extension is resolved using the [resolve.extensions](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/#resolveextensions) option, which tells the resolver which extensions are acceptable for resolution, e.g. `.js`, `.jsx`. More on the official [doc](https://webpack.js.org/concepts/module-resolution/#module-paths).

- If you are using ES modules with Node.js or in the browser without any compilation step:

> A file extension must be provided when using the `import` keyword to resolve relative or absolute specifiers... This behavior matches how `import` behaves in browser environments...  More on the official [doc](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#mandatory-file-extensions).

- If you are using CommonJS modules with Node.js:

> If the exact filename is not found, then Node.js will attempt to load the required filename with the added extensions: `.js`, `.json`, and finally `.node`. More on the official [doc](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#file-modules).

Comment: I switched from `require - commonjs` to `ES`. in Commonjs I did not use file extensions, now I have to add them because otherwise the nodeserver will fail. But adding .ts I get the error: `Unknown file extension ".ts" for..`.

Comment: Above it'a about vanilla JS. If you are using TypeScript, you should follow `tsc` configuration guidelines. You can read how TS works with modules [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html).

Comment: @Timo ironically, you may have to add ".js" even though they are typescript files you want to include. That's how we get around it right now. Looking more into it though.

Comment: TypeScript never translates import paths, that's a policy decision the team insisted on several times in TypeScript-issue discussions on GitHub. That's why it indeed supports `.js` endings in the code, since `.ts[x]` extensions would make no sense since they don't work at runtime and a process other than tsc - which refuses to do it - would have to rewrite them.

Comment: The state of JS right now is depressing. ES Modules are the most anti-developer thing I've ever seen