# Why do I need to include ".js" extension in Typescript import for custom module?

Tags: typescript, module

Very simple test of async/wait and I have a module that includes simple class to implement a delay function

`mymodule.ts`:

```
export class foo {

    public async delay(t: number) {
                console.log("returning prmise");
                return new Promise( resolve => setTimeout(resolve, t));
    };
};
```

simple top level TypeScript file to call the function:

`hello.ts`:

```
import { foo } from './mymodule'

let f = new foo();

console.log("start");
await f.delay(4000);
console.log("done");here
```

builds fine but when I run the resulting hello.js with node (>node hello.js) I get:

```
Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find module 'E:\tsdev\test\out\mymodule' imported from E:\tsdev\test\out\hello.js
Did you mean to import ../mymodule.js?
    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:399:5)
    at finalizeResolution (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:326:11)
    at moduleResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:945:10)
    at defaultResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:1153:11)
    at nextResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:163:28)
    at ESMLoader.resolve (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:838:30)
    at ESMLoader.getModuleJob (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:424:18)
    at ModuleWrap.<anonymous> (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:77:40)
    at link (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:76:36) {
  code: 'ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND'
}
```

if I add ".js" to make the import `import { foo } from './mymodule.js'`
it also builds just fine and now the application works as expected....

```bash
E:\tsdev\test\out>node hello.js
start
returning prmise
done
```

I'm sure it's something simple and stupid but I certainly can't find the issue.

Shawn

tried various changes to tsconfig and package files.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When do we need to add file extension when importing JavaScript modules?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72491392/when-do-we-need-to-add-file-extension-when-importing-javascript-modules)

Comment: ESM modules require you to specify the file extension. That's just how it is.

Comment: Found this - seems to salve issue but not sure I'm comfortable in the long term using an "experimental" parameter.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62619058/appending-js-extension-on-relative-import-statements-during-typescript-compilat

Comment: Possible solution I wrote (custom esm loader which works like TypeScript): https://github.com/olalonde/ts-module-loader

Answer (score 5):

If you want to use the official TypeScript compiler to generate JavaScript, you have to add the extension because

1. [Node.js refuses to allow extensionless relative imports](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/46006)
2. [TypeScript refuses to add import extensions at compile time](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/16577)

If you want or need to write extensionless imports in TypeScript, you need a bundler or an alternative build tool that can add the .js extensions. For example, you can transpile TypeScript to JavaScript using Babel and [babel-plugin-add-import-extension](https://codeberg.org/karl/babel-plugin-add-import-extension.git).

However, you'll still need TypeScript (`tsc`) itself to do type checking and generate type declaration files, so you'll need a tsconfig.json with `compilerOptions.moduleResolution` set to `"Bundler"`.

Here's my configuration for a library that targets Node.js 18.

.babelrc:

```json
{
  "presets": [
    [
      "@babel/env",
      {
        "modules": false,
        "targets": {
          "node": "18"
        }
      }
    ],
    "@babel/typescript"
  ],
  "plugins": ["add-import-extension"]
}
```

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "extends": "@tsconfig/strictest/tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowJs": false,
    "checkJs": false,
    "declaration": true,
    "declarationMap": true,
    "emitDeclarationOnly": true,
    "lib": ["ES2022"],
    "module": "ES2022",
    "moduleResolution": "Bundler",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "ES2022"
  }
}
```

package.json `scripts`:

```json
{
    "build": "run-p -s build:*",
    "build:main": "babel -x .ts -d dist src",
    "build:types": "tsc",
}
```

and some `devDependencies`:

```json
{
    "@babel/cli": "^7.22.15",
    "@babel/preset-typescript": "^7.22.15",
    "babel-plugin-add-import-extension": "^1.6.0",
    "npm-run-all": "^4.1.5",
    "typescript": "^5.2.2"
}
```